# CSS :has( :hover ) Selector

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get the following to work, but it doesn't work with the :hover selector:

```css
.a, .b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 25px;
}

.a:has(+ .b:hover) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Without the :hover selector, it works in Chrome and on Firefox with the `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` flag enabled.

```css
.a, .b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 25px;
}

.a:has(+ .b) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Is there any other way to get this to work?
The original intent is to have two lines of a table connected, so when one has a mouse over, both lines get highlighted.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: @CBroe sorry, you are right, it just doesn't work with :hover on Firefox, which is not enabled by default anyway.

Comment: _"it just doesn't work with :hover on Firefox, which is not enabled by default anyway"_ - which makes it unusable for "production" use anyway, unless you had a specific limited user base here.

Comment: @PandaSITT Are you wanting to change both to pink when either one is hovered?

Comment: @RyanWilson yes, highlighting the next sibling is easy enough, but there is no previous sibling selector.

Comment: @PandaSITT I have a working example in the answers

Comment: @RenevanderLende pseudo element != pseudo class. `:hover` belongs into the latter category.

Comment: @CBroe, my bad. Dang details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one that works for setting both `.a` and `.b` to pink on hover of either.

```css
.a, .b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 25px;
}

.a:hover,
.a:has(+ .b:hover)
{
  background: pink;
}

.b:hover,
.a:hover + .b
{
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Comment: this only works on chrome, but i guess the firefox is still buggy in this regard. thank you

Comment: @PandaSITT I guess you'll either need to find another css solution or use javascript if you plan to support Firefox. This works in Edge as well.

Comment: has is supported in all major browsers now so the solution is valid ✨